# get number value from input element in JQuery not works when float parts empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to code a currency converter, and only integer and float are allowed.So i detect the input change and do some calculation. 
html snippet is as below:

```
<input type="number" id="currency">
```

JS is:

```
$("#currency").on("input", function(e){
  var value = this.value
  console.log(value)
});
```

Everything works well except when input is "12.", the value is an empty string?
what i want is 12 actually. How to solve the issue? Any help would be appreciated.
[JSfiddle of snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/5snrsryy/6/)

Comment: Not sure I understand - the Fiddle seems to work fine for all numbers

Comment: If you try to input float number with just the dot, it will output an empty string

Comment: I still have 12 on the console when I input "12."

Comment: it is because, "12." is not a valid number (NaN)!

Comment: @TreeNguyen When you type **.**, the output is an empty string.

Comment: @jjk_charles yes, do you have any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: I have to type "12.." to actually get the empty string. "12." works fine for me

Comment: @TreeNguyen weird, in my side, one dot will show an empty string output.

Comment: @chancyWu what is the use case for this scenario. In most cases, treating  "12." as NaN sounds perfect to me!

Comment: @TreeNguyen which browser are you on?

Comment: @jjk_charles i am coding a currency converter, so if the dot is input, the value is 0, which actually is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `input type="number"`which wont allow any input other than number(including floating numbers).

But you put string or char as input you will see empty log statement and on doing `parseInt(this.value)` it will log `NaN`.

So if you still want to give string/number as a input you can use `input type="text"`

```
<input type="text" id="currency">
```

Comment: i want both float  and integer number actually~ if dot is not permitted in number type why it's allowed to be input?

Answer (score 1):

`Input type="number"` means any number including `float, integer` and does not allow to enter text. 
so the best solution might be  `Input type="text"` and if you want precision you can get by toFixed method as below example

```js
$("#currency").on("input", function(e){
var value = this.value
if(isNumeric(value)){
alert(parseInt(value));
} 
else{
alert("text")
}
   });

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="currency">
```

Comment: I want only integer and float number as input, if type is text, then normal character is allowed, which is another trouble now.

Comment: Hello @chancyWu , Check the fiddle is this the thing you are looking for  https://jsfiddle.net/3qqdy780/

Comment: please read my post again, i update it to make it more clear. thanks

Comment: @chancyWu, if you enter 12. if alerts 12 Please check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue is related to your localization.**

As everybody confirms, `<input type="number">` allows to enter integers *and* float.

So when typing `12.`, why do you get an empty result while some others get 12?
**Because their decimal point is dot, while yours is something else!**

E.g.: on my own system, where decimal point is comma, I get an empty result when typing `12.` and 12 when typing `12,`.